# Flutter Hello World app does not run on Emulator (android studio)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

[Flutter Hello world app doesn't start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHIHt.png)
Hello devs,

Trying Flutter for the first time (on android Studio) after completing installation, I try to run the Hello World app. However, after pressing 'run', nothing happens. Flutter Doctor says everyting is good.

as the image shows, nothing happens, even a long time after pressing 'run'
Desperately looking for help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long have you wait after you press start/run button?

Your console is showing a message "Running Gradle task...", it could mains you app is still running/compiling and you have to wait for a while. It may take several minutes. Normally it takes 1-2 minutes. However, the longest waiting/compiling time from what I know could be 20 minutes. It mainly depends on if your computer is fast enough. In some rare cases, long compiling time could mean your Gradle damaged or out of date.

If you are still not sure about this. Open CMD tool and go to your project folder. Then type in "flutter doctor -v". If you see any error message, you can fix it as it guided you. If no error message, you are good to run your app.